# $P(\sup X_t\ge x)=1/x$ if $\lim_{t\to \infty}X_t=0$ a.s. and $X_0 = 1$

Tags: probability

Let $X_t$ be a continuous non-negative martingale with $\lim_{t\to \infty}X_t=0$ a.s. and $X_0 = 1$.

Then how to show
\begin{equation}
P(\sup X_t\ge x)=\frac1x
\end{equation}
for any $x\ge1$ and $t\ge 0$?

I want to introduce stopping time $T_x$, but clearly I can not use optional stopping time here ($T_x$ is not a.s. finite). What should I do?

Comment: "clearly I cannot use optional stopping time here" Hmmm... why?

Comment: @Did Maybe I am wrong?Because $T_x$ is even not a.s. finite......

Comment: Then do as one always do, first use $\min(t,T_x)$ then let $t\to\infty$.

Comment: @Did It works,thanks!

Comment: It looks like the OP was able to solve the problem, but I would like to know how $T_x$ is defined and to what martingale we are applying the OST...

Comment: @Filippo The answer is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1239982/316409) , which means that this is a duplicate question. It is a generalization, given that $M_0$ is assumed to have a more arbitrary distribution than what is in this question.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1239524/prove-mathbbp-sup-t-geq-0-m-t-x-mid-mathcalf-0-1-wedge-fracm) is a duplicate question, a slightly more general one but close enough to this one.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thank you very much! I am typing on my phone, I will study the answers as soon as I am back home.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I think that you sent the same link twice, didn't you? Did you do this on purpose or is there as second duplicate?

Comment: @Filippo Sorry : the first comment was addressed to you, so that I could inform you that the question was answered very well elsewhere. The second comment is the default duplicate comment when one votes to close as a duplicate ("Does this answer your question?" ...) but I am pretty confident so I reworded that comment to make it an assertion. The link in both comments is the same, but one is meant for you to look at and the other for duplicate closers.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Filippo You are welcome!