# Follow-up to "Prove $\mathbb{P}(\sup_{t \geq 0} M_t > x \mid \mathcal{F}_0)= 1 \wedge \frac{M_0}{x}$ for..."

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, conditional-expectation, martingales

I don't understand the accepted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1239982/572841) to the following question:

> Let $M$ be a positive, continuous martingale that converges a.s. to zero as $t$
> tends to infinity. I now want to prove that for every $x>0$
> $$ P\left( \sup_{t \geq 0 } M_t > x \mid \mathcal{F}_0 \right) = 1 \wedge \frac{M_0}{x}. $$

The accepted answer shows that
$$\forall k:M_0 1_{\{M_0>x\}} + 1_{\{M_0 \leq x\}} x P(\tau < k \mid F_0) + E(M_k 1_{\{\tau \geq k\}} \mid F_0) = M_0$$
with $\tau := \inf\{t\geq 0 : M_t>x\}$. It then says that we obtain the desired equation by considering the limit
$k\to\infty$ and this is the part I don't understand.

**Edit**: I think that I solved the problem thanks to a hint in the comments. It looks like the problem is much less trivial than I expected, maybe someone can confirm this:

On the one hand, we have
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}E(M_k 1_{\{\tau \geq k\}} \mid F_0)=0$$
since "M converges to zero" (DCT). Thus we obtain:
$$M_0 1_{\{x<M_0\}} + 1_{\{M_0 \leq x\}} x P(\tau < \infty \mid F_0)= M_0$$
Since $0<x$, this is equivalent to:
$$ 1_{\{x<M_0\}}\frac{M_0}{x} + 1_{\{M_0 \leq x\}} P(\tau < \infty \mid F_0)=\frac{ M_0}{x}$$
And this is equivalent to:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
1_{\{M_0 \leq x\}} P(\tau < \infty \mid F_0)=\frac{ M_0}{x}-1_{\{M_0>x\}}\frac{M_0}{x} =1_{\{M_0\leq x\}}\frac{M_0}{x}
\end{equation}
On the other hand, we can use
$$1\wedge\frac{M_0}{x}=1_{\{x<M_0\}}+1_{\{M_0\leq x\}}\frac{M_0}{x}$$
and
$$P(x<\sup_{t}M_t\mid F_0)=P(\tau<\infty\mid F_0)$$
(see the comments) to rewrite the desired result:
$$P(\tau<\infty\mid F_0)=1_{\{x<M_0\}}+1_{\{M_0\leq x\}}\frac{M_0}{x}$$
But this equation follows from $(1)$ and the fact that $1_{\{x<M_0 \}} P(\tau < \infty \mid F_0)=1_{\{x<M_0 \}}$:
\begin{equation}
P(\tau < \infty \mid F_0)=1_{\{M_0 \leq x\}} P(\tau < \infty \mid F_0)+1_{\{x<M_0 \}} P(\tau < \infty \mid F_0)=1_{\{M_0 \leq x\}} \frac{M_0}{x}+1_{\{x<M_0 \}} 
\end{equation}

Comment: I'm sorry, I took a look at your comment in that place once you called me, but I'm way too busy today to answer this question, and I hope you'll get it!

Comment: You are assuming that $\tau <\infty$ a.s. but this is not true.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer No problem, thank you for the comment!

Comment: @geetha290krm Ah, I didn't know that the infimum of the empty set is equal to $\infty$. That's the point, right? I.e. $\tau=\infty\Leftrightarrow\forall t:M_t\leq x$?